# Why release ID is confused with actual build number - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, build

Windows 10 has several release IDs which can we upgrade I.E. 2004. Now when we see at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` we get two different values `ReleaseId` and `BuildNumber` and their data are different. ReleaseID contains the number which we refer to the "build" I.E. 2004 and the build number is completely different.

So my questions are:

- Why Release ID and Actual build number is confused?
- Then what is the use of actual build number (Not release ID)

Comment: Windows 10 has always operated like this, with both a version number, which is the last two digits of the year followed by the month of the bi-annual release _(prior to 2020, the release to the Insider channel in March and September, with a mainstream release the following month)_, and a build [revision] number; both can be seen by issuing `winver` in a terminal or `WinKey`+`R`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2004 Number is the Version (1903, 1909, 2004)

The OS Build is the set of numbers that follow. e.g. 19041.329

It has shown up like this for a while and I use Start, Settings, System, About to see this.

[image]

Then see this registry screenshot that supports the About screen above.

[image]